# Replacing Fedora 15 with Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, installation, dual-boot, windows-7, fedora

I am new to the Linux world and have been experimenting with a Windows 7/ Fedora 15 dual boot system, and now I would like to remove Fedora and install Ubuntu 11 instead.

Can anyone tell me the steps required for installing Ubuntu over Fedora the and what possible traps there are to watch out for (I tried this once and nearly lost everything).

any help would be appreciated.

---

thanks for the replies, I have been looking into this a little with regard to my partitions.

My hard drive has the usual windows 7 partitions at the begining of the disk, then I have an extended partition listed as /dev/sda4/ "Extended partition (0x05)" at the end of the drive.

This sda4 partion seems to be then sub divied into teo further partitions sda5 and sda6. sda5 is a 500mb ext4 linux partition mounted as /boot, which i'm guessing houses the grub boot manager for fedora.  sda6 is the linux LVM partition which is itself subdivied into yet more partitions containing the swap space and the /home space.

my questions is: for installing Ubuntu do I simply select to install over the entire sda4 partition which I assume will over-write the boot partition or install ubuntu into sda6 and just overwrite fedora.

I briefly tried to install ubuntu over sda4 and although the install process claimed to have complteted no boot loader system was installed, which meant no windows and no ubuntu. re-installing fedora from USB drive re-installed the boot system and allowed me to get back to windows.

should Ubuntu have automatically installed a Grub boot loader?

Thanks

Wisty

Comment: What is your partition structure?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have anything valuable in your Fedora, you can just boot from Ubuntu Live CD and install over Fedora (choose manual partitioning, select Fedora's root partition as your root partition, tick Format, etc.)

If you have anything valuable there, then you need to make a backup first. If your /home is on a separate partition you can keep the data there, but having a backup is still a good precaution.

Answer (score 1):

1. BACKUP YOUR STUFF IN FEDORA BEFORE YOU DO THIS!!!
2. Restore the windows MBR using [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net)
3. Boot into windows and delete the Fedora Partitions
4. Install Ubuntu!

Good Luck!  I tried this before when I had a crippled Ubuntu Installation.  It worked for me